# A class method which behaves differently when called as an instance method?

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm wondering if it's possible to make a method which behaves differently when called as a class method than when called as an instance method.

For example, as a skills-improvement project, I'm writing a `Matrix` class (yes, I know there are perfectly good matrix classes already out there). I've created a class method for it called `identity` which returns an identity matrix of a specified size.

Now, when called on an *instance* of `Matrix`, it seems logical that the size shouldn't need to be specified; it should return an identity matrix of the same size as the `Matrix` it's called on.

In other words, I'd like to define a method which can determine whether it was called via an instance and, if so, access that instance's attributes.  Unfortunately, even after digging through the documentation and a few Google searches, I haven't found anything which suggests this is possible.  Does anyone know differently?

**Edit:**

Wow!  Clearly, I'm still not quite used to first-class functions.  Here's what I ended up with — thanks to Unknown for providing the key!

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.baz = bar
        self.bar = MethodType(lambda self: self.__class__.bar(self.baz), self, self.__class__)

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls, baz):
        return 5 * baz

Foo.bar(3) # returns 15

foo = Foo(7)
foo.bar() # returns 35
```

**Edit 2:**

Just a quick note — this technique (and most of those presented below) won't work on classes which define `__slots__`, as you cannot reassign the method.

Comment: The question asked for a single callable object that could detect how it was called.  (This should be possible using the inspect module to get the calling frame.) The 'solution' presented is to create a second callable, a bound method, that is bound to each instance with the same name as the first callable.  This may solve the problem of how to have class and 'instance methods' with the same name.  But it is not the same as having a single callable that can act as either.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy is it possible to inspect the calling frame at runtime?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant by "use the inspect module to get the calling frame".  There are one or more functions for this.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Questionably useful Python hacks are my forte.

```
from types import *

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = methodize(bar, self)
        self.baz = 999

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls, baz):
        return 2 * baz


def methodize(func, instance):
    return MethodType(func, instance, instance.__class__)

def bar(self):
    return 4*self.baz


>>> Foo.bar(5)
10
>>> a=Foo()
>>> a.bar()
3996
```

Comment: Kudos, and an upvote, for effort in the code sample, and especially for the phrase "questionably useful Python hacks are my forte" :-)

Comment: @Jarret, its not just a quote for show either. Check out my other ones such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813882/is-there-a-way-to-check-whether-function-output-is-assigned-to-a-variable-in-pyth/813938#813938

Comment: Ok, thats nice. Now how do you pickle this ?

Answer (score 7):

**[edited: use attribute to be a more direct answer; see the helpful comment by John Fouhy]**

You can use a descriptor to do what you want:

```
class cls_or_inst_method(object):
    def __init__(self, class_method, instance_method):
        self.class_method = class_method
        self.instance_method = instance_method

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        if obj is None:
            return self.class_method
        else:
            return lambda: self.instance_method(obj)

def my_class_method(baz):
    return baz + 1

def my_instance_method(self):
    return self.baz * 2

class Foo(object):
    baz = 10
    bar = cls_or_inst_method(my_class_method, my_instance_method)
```

Using the above:

```
>>> print Foo.bar(5)
6
>>> my_foo = Foo()
>>> print my_foo.bar()
20
```

Comment: To be a solution, the instance method should refer to self.baz and not take any arguments (except self), I think..

Answer (score 7):

@Unknown What's the difference between your's and this:

```
class Foo(object):

    def _bar(self, baz):
        print "_bar, baz:", baz

    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = self._bar
        self.baz = bar

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls, baz):
        print "bar, baz:", baz

In [1]: import foo

In [2]: f = foo.Foo(42)

In [3]: f.bar(1)
_bar, baz: 1

In [4]: foo.Foo.bar(1)
bar, baz: 1

In [5]: f.__class__.bar(1)
bar, baz: 1
```

Comment: Well the difference is that you can bind whatever function you want as the method. I just used this opportunity to show off that trick. And also that there is no dangling f._bar()

Comment: @Unknown: if the "dangling" `f._bar()` is an issue, then just define it using a lambda or nested function inside the `__init__()`  This code here is intuitively obvious how it works, whereas the other solution involves obscure Python voodoo, not to mention module visible top level functions `methodize()` and `bar()`

Answer (score 3):

I think the larger problem is that you are overloading the name 'bar' on class 'Foo', something python doesn't allow.  The second definition of 'bar' clobbers the first definition of 'bar'.

Try to think of unique names for your classmethod and instance method.  i.e.

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, baz):
   ...

def rubber_stamp(self):
   ...
```

Comment: +1: And -- of course -- the inherent confusion factor of variant behavior, even if "closely related".

Comment: And your suggestion to fix the "non-working concept code" that the OP already identified as a large problem with which he needs help is?

Comment: IMO, the non-working concept code is a bad idea -- the fix is to rethink the API.  There's no "fix".

Answer (score 2):

You can reassign your identity method in **init** with short lambda function:

```
class Matrix(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.identity = lambda s=self:s.__class__.identity(s)

        #...whatever initialization code you have...
        self.size = 10        

    @classmethod
    def identity(self, other):
        #...always do you matrix calculations on 'other', not 'self'...
        return other.size


m = Matrix()
print m.identity()
print Matrix.identity(m)
```

If you're not familiar with lambda, it creates an anonymous function. It's rarely necessary, but it can make your code more concise. The lambda line above could be rewritten:

```
    def identity(self):
        self.__class__.indentity(self)
    self.identity = identity
```